# Button clicked on ADF pagefragment-exception occurred.Other buttons(previously working) stopped working, throwing same exception

Tags: oracle-adf, page-fragments

In my ADF application, there is a base page template with two major facets- leftNav and center. Page fragment mainNav.jsff that contains the buttons is added on the leftNav. According to the button clicked, page fragment is displayed in the center facet.

Everthing was working but I am facing a problem that if I click on one button in mainNav.jsff and ANY exception occurs then all other buttons stops working and throws the same exception.

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3 and Weblogic 11gR1. I am using ADF Faces only.
Why is this exception coming and how can I solve this problem?

edit :
Current Exception is

```
    <RegistrationConfigurator> <handleError> ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #2
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.util.ELInterfaceImpl.setExpression(ELInterfaceImpl.java:122)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.setInputValues(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:848)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.enterTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:592)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeLocalTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:324)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:227)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:223)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ChildViewPortContextImpl.invokeTaskFlow(ChildViewPortContextImpl.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState.createChildViewPort(ControllerState.java:1255)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.ControllerContextImpl.createChildViewPort(ControllerContextImpl.java:80)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.createRegionViewPortContext(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:416)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.getViewPort(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:313)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.doProcessBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:159)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.processBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:255)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:134)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3237)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3228)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.FacesPageLifecycle.prepareModel(FacesPageLifecycle.java:392)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:149)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$400(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:238)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:274)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:75)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:447)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<RichExceptionHandler> <_logUnhandledException> ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.util.ELInterfaceImpl.setExpression(ELInterfaceImpl.java:122)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.setInputValues(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:848)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.enterTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:592)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeLocalTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:324)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:227)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:223)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ChildViewPortContextImpl.invokeTaskFlow(ChildViewPortContextImpl.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState.createChildViewPort(ControllerState.java:1255)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.ControllerContextImpl.createChildViewPort(ControllerContextImpl.java:80)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.createRegionViewPortContext(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:416)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.getViewPort(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:313)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.doProcessBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:159)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.processBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:255)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:134)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3237)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3228)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.FacesPageLifecycle.prepareModel(FacesPageLifecycle.java:392)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:149)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$400(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:238)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:274)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:75)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:447)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<RegistrationConfigurator> <handleError> ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #3
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.util.ELInterfaceImpl.setExpression(ELInterfaceImpl.java:122)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.setInputValues(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:848)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.enterTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:592)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeLocalTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:324)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.invokeTaskFlow(TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.java:227)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:223)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ChildViewPortContextImpl.invokeTaskFlow(ChildViewPortContextImpl.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState.createChildViewPort(ControllerState.java:1255)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.ControllerContextImpl.createChildViewPort(ControllerContextImpl.java:80)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.createRegionViewPortContext(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:416)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.getViewPort(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:313)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.doProcessBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:159)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.processBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:255)
    at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:134)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3237)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3228)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:2906)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:115)
    at oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.FacesPageLifecycle.prepareModel(FacesPageLifecycle.java:392)
    at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:149)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.access$400(ADFPhaseListener.java:23)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$PhaseInvokerImpl.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:238)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:274)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:75)
    at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:447)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:173)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are people just supposed to guess what the exception is?

Comment: This question is indeed not very complete. Provide more context. Code, error messages, ...

Answer (score 0):

In Page View parameter instead of `#{sessionScope.Temp}` you might have given `#(sessionScope.Temp}`

Wrong brace `()` instead of `{}`, please check.
I had the same issue, solved after long debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Lets decode your stack trace:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException
...
TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.setInputValues()
...
TaskFlowCallActivityLogic.enterTaskFlow()
```

You are opening a task flow from the menu by passing an input parameter to the task flow and this parameter is readOnly. You may check your task flow parameters and make them all editable if they are associated with backing beans.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing parameters to a page or between task flows and the EL is incorrect.

[Here is a screenshot in JDev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc1hY.png)

you may also have "scope.variable" instead of "#{scope.variable}"